# How do i add a cmd delete option to the right click context menu in window 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, console

I want to delete a large number of files from a USB hard drive, I found that a faster way to delete is to use the cmd console delete function. I would like to add the option to do this into the context menus for files and for folders.

I found [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/18/how-to-delete-large-folders-in-windows-super-fast/) tutorial that shows to create a .bat file and add it to the registry, however when I try to use it nothing happens, I did manage to get the option to appear in the context menu by adding the key to **Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Fast Delete\command** instead of the **Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Fast Delete\command** like it says in the tutorial, although when I try to use it from the right click nothing happens.

The .bat file is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Delete Folder: %CD%?
PAUSE
SET FOLDER=%CD%
CD /
DEL /F/Q/S "%FOLDER%" > NUL
RMDIR /Q/S "%FOLDER%"
EXIT
```

and the location of the .bat file is **"C:\Extra Windows Tools\delete.bat"** i did add **"C:\Extra Windows Tools** to the system path variable.

I have tried using **cmd /c "cd %1 && delete.bat"** like the tutorial says and nothing happens I have also tried **"C:\Extra Windows Tools\delete.bat" %1**, that I found on another website.

Any help that you can give will be greatly appreciated

*Edit 1
The problem is partly to do with permissions and partly because it doesnt seem to work when i right click on folders only on files. with the permissions problems i go through [these](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container) steps which allows me to delete files using the normal delete option but not with the batch script.

*Edit 2 - I have sorted the permissions, the problem is because the script doesnt seem to work on folders

*Edit 3 - I have fixed the problem, i added the key with the suggestion below to **Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Fast Delete** and it now works on folders. Thank you for all your suggestions

Comment: What debugging / troubleshooting have you done? Have you tried temporarily renaming the script, and then clicking on the menu entry — to see whether it gives you an error message? Have you tried writing to a log file from the batch file? Do you expect a CMD window to pop up when you do this? (Have you seen anything that would suggest that this will happen?) If not, what do you expect to happen when you `pause`?

Comment: To be completely honest this is the first time i have tried anything like this i will try your suggestions,

Comment: I changed the command key to the location of the .bat file again and tried it out on a random file in a folder on my c drive and it worked a menu popped up asked for any key then deleted it, however when i tried to use this on my USB hard drive (taken from a previous laptop) the console flashes up then dissapears, what should i do?

Comment: [Edit] your question and include all information about what you have tried and what happened.

Comment: You will need to restart Explorer for the system environment variable to be read. If you reboot, make sure you use `Restart`, not `Shut down`, as with default settings this hibernates, which doesn't restart anything.

Comment: How would I add a log to the .bat file?

Comment: Before you worry about the log, reboot the machine, and update your question.

Comment: Ok, i will do that now

Comment: I have just restarted, the fast delete tool works when used in my c drive, but when i try it on my USB hard drive F, it still flashes open and closes.

Comment: I think the problem is to do with permissions, some of the files are refusing to allow full control by admin and user accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is partly to do with permissions and partly because it doesnt seem to work when i right click on folders only on files. with the permissions problems i go through these steps which allows me to delete files using the normal delete option but not with the batch script.

I have fixed the problem, i added the key with the suggestion below to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Fast Delete and it now works on folders.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "%1" with "%V" in the registry key for right click menus. This will pass the object that was clicked on.